# .NET 4 - Using nullable operator (??) to simplify if statements

Tags: .net-4.0

I have this piece of code, that checks whether a returned object is null. If so, it will return 0, or else it will return a property inside the object.

```
var userPoints = (from Point p in entities.Point
                 where p.UserName == userName
                 select p).SingleOrDefault();

        if (userPoints == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            return userPoints.Points;
        }
```

Is it possible to simplify the if statements with the nullable operator? I've tried this, but the system throws an exception when attempting to read the property

```
return userPoints.Points ?? 0;
```

Comment: The coalesce operator (??) was already introduced in .NET 2.0, not 4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately there's nothing which will do exactly that. Options:

- Use the conditional operator:

  ```
  return userPoints == null ? 0 : userPoints.Points;
  ```
- Change your query to make *that* do the defaulting:

  ```
  return (from Point p in entities.Point
          where p.UserName == userName
          select p.Points).SingleOrDefault();
  ```

Personally I'd go for the latter approach :) If you wanted a default other than 0, you'd need something like:

```
return (from Point p in entities.Point
        where p.UserName == userName
        select (int?) p.Points).SingleOrDefault() ?? -1;
```

Comment: Sometimes you get stuck thinking using a feature to do what you can't do, and the right answer is actually so obvious...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
  var userPoints = (from Point p in entities.Point
                   where p.UserName == userName
                   select p.Point).SingleOrDefault();
  return userPoints;
```

If there are no results then userPoints will be 0, otherwise it will be the value of Points.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use it in your context.
Explanation:
You want to check whether `userPoints` is null, but want to return `userPoints.Points` if it is not null.
The `??` operator checks the first operand for null and returns it, if it is not null. It doesn't work if what you want to check and what you want to return are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Hover over `var` with the mouse and see what type it is.

Comment: How is that going to automatically get the Points property though?

Comment: Well once he's hovered over the var he will know what type is being returned and that seemed to be where the confusion was coming from.

Comment: @B Tyler: Did you edit your answer? I think it was different when I made the comment...